# Xamarin forms CFB notification: How to refresh token after once registeration device?

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin, push-notification

I created the application with Xamarin.forms.iOS and use Plugin.FirebasePushNotification to send the notification through firebase.

once I registered the device there no problem with getting Token, but, after I delete app and test again the app doesn't get the Token.
I cannot receive the notification anymore.

AppDelegate.cs

```
[Register("AppDelegate")]
public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
{
    NSDictionary _launchOptions;
    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
        ImageCircleRenderer.Init();
        LoadApplication(new App());
        AnimationViewRenderer.Init();

        _launchOptions = options;

        Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.CurrentPlatform.Init();
        SQLitePCL.Batteries.Init();

        ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.iOS.Platform.Init();
        FirebasePushNotificationManager.Initialize(options, true);

        if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(10, 0))
        {
            UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.RequestAuthorization(UNAuthorizationOptions.Alert | UNAuthorizationOptions.Sound | UNAuthorizationOptions.Sound,
                                                                    (granted, error) =>
                                                                    {
                                                                        if (granted)
                                                                            InvokeOnMainThread(UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications);
                                                                    });
        }
        else if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(8, 0))
        {
            var pushSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes(
                    UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound,
                    new NSSet());

            UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings(pushSettings);
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications();
        }
        else
        {
            UIRemoteNotificationType notificationTypes = UIRemoteNotificationType.Alert | UIRemoteNotificationType.Badge | UIRemoteNotificationType.Sound;
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotificationTypes(notificationTypes);
        }


        CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnTokenRefresh += (s, p) =>
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"TOKEN : {p.Token}");
            UIPasteboard clipboard = UIPasteboard.General;
            clipboard.String = p.Token;
            Helper.Settings.Token = p.Token;

        };

        CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationReceived += (s, p) =>
        {
            Dictionary<string, object> dic = p.Data as Dictionary<string, object>;
            if (dic["targetUserId"].ToString() != null && Helper.Settings.UserId == dic["targetUserId"].ToString())
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Received");
                Helper.Settings.userWhoSentNotiId = dic["userWhoSentNotiId"].ToString();
                Helper.Settings.callingStatus = true;                 FirebasePushNotificationManager.CurrentNotificationPresentationOption = UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Alert;
                MessagingCenter.Send<object, string>(this, "CallingNotifications", dic["callingName"].ToString());
            }
        };

        CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationOpened += (s, p) =>
        {
            Dictionary<string, object> dic = p.Data as Dictionary<string, object>;
            Helper.Settings.userWhoSentNotiId = dic["userWhoSentNotiId"].ToString();
            Helper.Settings.callingStatus = true;
            MessagingCenter.Send<object, string>(this, "CallingNotifications", dic["callingName"].ToString());
        };
        return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
    }

    public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
    {
        FirebasePushNotificationManager.DidRegisterRemoteNotifications(deviceToken);
    }

    public override void FailedToRegisterForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSError error)
    {
        FirebasePushNotificationManager.RemoteNotificationRegistrationFailed(error);
    }

    public override void DidReceiveRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo, Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)
    {
        FirebasePushNotificationManager.DidReceiveMessage(userInfo);
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData);
    }
}
```

I notice the app don't launch 
CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnTokenRefresh

How can the app refresh the token?

Comment: What is the error message? Have you try to registere the device?

Comment: @WendyZang
there is no error message but **p.Token** in
**Helper.Settings.Token = p.Token;** line is empty. 
I tried to debug this line it don't be executed.
I don't know why and how to fix this.

Comment: This occurred when you deleted the app, do you try to create a matching app in firebase to test again?

Comment: @WendyZang yes! 
but it cannot receive token. 
How the refresh token work?
and How can I fix this?
thank you

Comment: I try to delete app and recreate it again. Maybe it is similar. I could not get the token with no error. You could try to create a app in FCM with the same package name. And delete the bin and obj folder of your project and add the new json file. Please note you need to uninstall the app in you phone frst. Please make sure your device have connected to the internet.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, I already did like you said but nothing change.
I cannot get Token from FCM